# How to test if a certain differential equation has an analytic solution (solution has Taylor expansion)?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analytic-functions, analyticity

How to test if the differential equation

$$(1+x)y'''+y y''-y'^2+(2+x)y''+y'=0,$$
$$y(0)=1, y'(0)=1, y'(\infty)=0$$

Has an analytic solution? Solution that equals its Taylor series?

Comment: You should be able to find statements that ODE with analytical right side have local solutions that are analytical. A different question is if the boundary conditions can be satisfied.

Comment: @LutzLehmann could you please give me a reference or some link to read about such statements?

Comment: Yup, of course. Thanks, @Thomas. I will delete :)